# How can I keep my current page inside the Bootstrap ul?

Tags: css, pagination, jstl

[image: picture of current page number displayed outside of normal area]

I'm using Bootstrap to make my pagination created with JSTL tags look better. For some reason, the current page number situates itself to the right, outside of the bootstrap styling. Can anyone tell me why my code does this and how to fix it? Thank you!

```
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li><c:if test="${currentPage != 1}">
                    <a href="event.do?page=${currentPage - 1}" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </c:if></li>
            <c:forEach begin="1" end="${noOfPages}" var="i">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${currentPage eq i}">
                        <li>${i}</li>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <li><a href="event.do?page=${i}">${i}</a></li>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </c:forEach>
            <li><c:if test="${currentPage lt noOfPages}">
                    <a href="event.do?page=${currentPage + 1}" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </c:if></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think the markup looks correct (I am not familiar with JSTL), but as a test I would try to wrap your current page number in a `<a href="#"></a>` and see if that makes a difference. So it would be `<li><a href="#">${i}</a></li>`

Comment: Yes! It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your current page number in an anchor tag with `href="#"`.

Like this:

`<li><a href="#">${i}</a></li>`

I think probably because Bootstrap styling for pagination requires the markup `ul > li > a`.